# What controllers can you use on Minecraft for Wii-U

Tags: controllers, wii-u, minecraft-legacy-console

On Minecraft for the Wii-U I have heard you cannot use the Wii remote or nun-chuck, is this true? What are the controllers you can use?

Answer (score 5):

> On minecraft for the Wii-U I have heard you cannot use the Wii remote or nun-chuck, is this true?

Yes, this is indeed true.

> What are the controllers you can use?

You can use the Wii U GamePad, and the Wii U Pro Controller in local gameplay, as shown in this article. [Minecraft Wii U Edition: Review](http://www.nintendolife.com/reviews/wiiu-eshop/minecraft_wii_u_edition)

Comment: Third party controllers are known not to work properly at present: www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-wii-u-edition/mcwiiu-discussion/2578642-minecraft-wii-u-edition-has-a-problem-with-wii-u

Comment: Well that's complete and utter BS.  I'm not buying more controllers.  My kids just want to play minecraft with each other.

Comment: @Mike I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

Once in game using pro controller press the "A" button and the screen will ask you to join and then you click the "A" button again.